# ¿Cual es la diferencia entre StringBuilder y StringBuffer? en Java

Tags: java

Creo que ***StringBuilder*** y ***StringBuffer*** en *Java* tienen la misma funcionalidad. ¿Cuál es la principal diferencia?

Comment: Puedes consultar la Api oficial para más info:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html

Answer (score 5):

La mayor diferencia entre ambas clases es que [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) tiene todos sus métodos sincronizados para "soporte de escritura concurrente", mientras que [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) no los tiene.

Dado esto, el rendimiento de `StringBuilder` será mayor al de `StringBuffer` en todas sus operaciones.

Si necesitas concatenar muchas cadenas/caracteres/números dentro de un método que se invoca dentro de un hilo, lo más recomendable es usar `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte, entonces entiendo que si invoco mediante uno o varios hilos es recomendable utilizar StringBuilder?

Comment: Si vas a concatenar muchas cadenas, caracteres y demás elementos en un solo hilo, usa `StringBuilder`. Si tu cadena necesita armarse dentro de un ambiente multi hilos, entonces usa `StringBuffer`. Ojo, no basta que el ambiente sea una aplicación multi hilos, sino que el fragmento de código donde necesitas armar la cadena está afectado por 2 o más hilos trabajando concurrentemente.

Answer (score 0):

sobre string builder te puedo decir que es parecida a string, la diferencia esta en:
 cuando creas objetos string, estos se guardan en el string pool (un sitio especial de java donde guarda los objetos para ser usados). Si a una cadena que ya esta guardada en el string pool le concatenas otra...en el string pool aparecen 2 cadenas, pues la primera no se modifica...simplemente se copia con la modificacion.
 StringBuilder es lo contrario...este tipo de cadenas si se modifican sin copiarse en el string pool...asi modifiques una cadena la misma no se copia con la modificacion, sino que esta si se modifica quedando una sola en el stringpool.
Te recomiendo leer sobre el heap de java y la pila de java 
respecto de StringBuffer no te puedo ayudar